# Favicon showing when testing file but not when hosted

Tags: html, web-hosting, favicon

I am having issues trying to get the favicon to show for my site http://www.internhacks.io/.

When testing the file in Chrome, I am able to see it, and have the following in my `<head>` tag

```
    <link rel="icon" href="assets/img/favicon-@2x.png">
```

The project can be found [here](https://github.com/InternHacks/InternHacks.github.io) on Github.

The file structure is:

```
-README.md  
-favicon.ico    
-index.html
-assets
```

I am currently hosting the site with Namecheap and see no way to serve a favicon from there.

If anyone has experienced this before when hosting with Namecheap, or sees the issue, please let me know!

Comment: Your "structure" and your "href" appear to have absolutely nothing to do with each other

Comment: Upon viewing the favicon link on your website, the `href` field shows `_`

Answer (score 0):

I just visited http://www.internhacks.io/assets/img/favicon-@2x.png and I get the whole index.html page back. You may want to check your .htaccess rules for rewrites, to make sure that when requesting files, they can be received.